# SNS/SQS + MassTransit: Cannot publish an event to multiple consumers

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

I'm new to SNS and SQS with MassTransit (usually I use RabbitMQ) and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get it working properly. I'm building a scheduling service that broadcasts to all downstream services when any schedule is due, and then the downstream services decide whether or not they care.

My problem is that even though I have multiple consumers, only one SQS queue is created for the SNS topic representing the event. Once one of the consumers receives the message it triggers the visibility timeout and the other consumers never know about it.

In RabbitMQ one exchange could push a message to multiple queues. I might be getting confused by the AWS topology but shouldn't it be possible to create one queue for each consumer and prefix the service name (and probably also the scope)?

I would really appreciate any help with configuring MassTransit to create one queue for each consumer.

Here's my bus registration. I'm using Autofac for dependency injection.

```
builder.AddMassTransit(ctx =>
{                
    foreach (var type in consumers)
        ctx.AddConsumer(type);
            
    ctx.UsingAmazonSqs((context, configurator) =>
    {
        var lifetimeScopeFilter = context.GetService<LifetimeScopeFilter>();
        var configuration = context.GetService<IAppSettings>();
        configurator.UseFilter(lifetimeScopeFilter);
        configurator.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(LoggingFilter<>), context);
        configurator.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(SegmentFilter<>), context);

        var host = configuration.Get("Bus:Host");
        var scope = configuration.Get("Bus:Scope");
        var secretKey = configuration.Get("Bus:SecretKey");
        var accessKey = configuration.Get("Bus:AccessKey");

        configurator.Host(host, hostConfig =>
        {
            hostConfig.Scope(scope);
            hostConfig.SecretKey(secretKey);
            hostConfig.AccessKey(accessKey);
            hostConfig.EnableScopedTopics();
        });

        configurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
        {
            r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            r.Handle<DBConcurrencyException>();
        });

        configurator.UseTransaction(x =>
        {
            x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            x.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        });

        configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new DefaultEndpointNameFormatter($"{scope}-", true));
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with the configuration, if the scope is different it should create a unique queue. Check the Getting Started documentation, and I'm guessing you're on an older version of MassTransit since Autofac is no longer directly supported.

Comment: I really appreciate your response, Chris. I'm checking out the Getting Started video now.

Just so I'm clear: You're suggesting adding the application name to the scope? Do I need that for the host config as well as the endpoint name formatter?
`hostConfig.Scope($"{env}-{applicationName}")`
`cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new DefaultEndpointNameFormatter($"{env}-{applicationName}-", false));`